# How to: Lorenz curve (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to draw several Lorenz curves. I don't have concrete data point but have to illustrate in each case some general aspect of the concept. Compare e.g. Lorenz crossing:

[image]

It's not that important in which point those cross, but to illustrate the point. I have somehow the feeling that some TikZ solution would be more appropriate then the package `pst-func` (which did not work for me for any reason).

What would be a good starting point?

**Update**: My main problem is still the surrounding design of the box, e.g. this yields a nice box:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\tikzset{every picture/.style=semithick}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=left,
    axis line style={shorten < = -0.3cm}, 
  xmin=0,
  xmax=2.2,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=2.2,
  clip=false,
  xtick={0,...,1},
  ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=cumulative population,
    xlabel style={at={(current axis)}, yshift=-5.8cm, xshift=-1.3cm},
    ylabel=cumulative income,
    ylabel style={at={(current axis.north west)},rotate=-90,yshift=-19em, xshift=1.5cm},
]
\tiny
\draw %right border
  (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,2);
\draw % upper border 
  (axis cs:0,2) -- (axis cs:2,2);
\draw % diagonal
    (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:2,2);
\end{axis}
\normalsize
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

But it is no nice code to design the box by 2.2 units and scale everything down to \tiny ... but I don't find another method. The subsequent problem are the ticks, which I cannot use directly.

**Update2**:

The scaling advice is pretty good. But if I try to adjust the line width of the plots, they loose their tick symbols. Is there a way to add dots as connecting symbols? And to place the plot labels as extra text within the box?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=120mm, height=100mm, compat=newest}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
        ytick={100},
        xtick={0, 20,40,60,80,100},
        xlabel= \small cumulative population,
        xlabel style={at={(current axis.south east)}, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-1cm},
        ylabel= \small cumulative income,
        ylabel style={at={(current axis.north west)},rotate=-90,yshift=1cm, xshift=2cm},
    ]
\addplot[blue, line width=2pt] plot 
    coordinates { (0,0) (25,20) (50,15) (75,30) (100,100)};
\addplot[ForestGreen, line width=2pt] plot
    coordinates { (0,0) (25,10) (50,45) (75,40) (100,100)};

\addplot[line width=2pt] plot 
    coordinates { (0,0) (100,100)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Tikz has a data visualization library and pgfplots requires less manual intervention.  Both have very good manuals with lots of tutorials.

Comment: For changing with of diagram line, you need to give option to the `plot`, not to the `\addplot`, see upgrade of my answer.

Comment: By the way, what you have drawn are not Lorenz curves. you need to order your population in order of increasing incomes. So the gradient of your Lorenz curves must be always non-decreasing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For starting point: I use pgfplots. Most of the code is self-explanatory, for details, pleas read package manual:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=newest}
    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    minor tick num = 4,
    grid,
    ylabel = cumulative income (in \%),
    xlabel = cumulative population (in \%),
    legend style={legend pos=north west},
    ]
\addplot plot 
    coordinates { (0,0) (25,20) (50,15) (75,30) (100,100)};
\addplot plot
    coordinates { (0,0) (25,10) (50,45) (75,40) (100,100)};
\addplot plot [thin]
    coordinates { (0,0) (100,100)};
\legend{$L(1)$,$L(2)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Upgrade:**
For changing only width of diagram's lines, you should say:

```
\addplot plot[line width=2pt]
    coordinates { (0,0) (25,20) (50,15) (75,30) (100,100)};
```

Of course, you can change color to. For example, as you select in your upgraded questions:

```
\addplot plot[ForestGreen,line width=2pt]
    coordinates { (0,0) (25,20) (50,15) (75,30) (100,100)};
```

However, you need to change the appearance of mark to, otherwise they will have default color in the middle. This you can change with for example:

```
every mark/.append style={fill=white}
```

Well, this lead to more complicated code in carefully reading of pgfplots manual.

With above change you can obtain the following picture:

[image]

Comment: I now added my approach by now :)

Comment: So you would disadvise me from using multiple "draw" lines and connecting those. Your code is significantly smaller than mine, thx. Now I have an issue with the overall scaling, if I use [scale=1.5] the overall size on A4paper looks good. But it scales up all elements (e.g. font is too big / though lines still too thin). What would be the best approach for scaling?

Comment: Instead scaling try to define size of image, for example `\pgfplotsset{width=170mm, height=120mm, compat=newest}`. Width and height of image you can also define in axis option, on the same way as in `pgfplotsset`.